# Determining rare values from a noise generator? (Aka how does minecraft place ores)

Tags: generator, minecraft, perlin-noise

I'm currently working on a 2d world generator (Side scroller) using Perlin Noise, and I want to be able to have rare ores spread through the terrain - but I'm not entirely sure how to do it.

What I was thinking about doing, was while looping through the 2d array and generating the world, collect a list of all the numbers (Or number ranges) and adding them to an array - then determining the rarity of each number / range of numbers, and placing ores like that however...

That just seems slow and there *has* to be a faster, better way. Is there?

**Edit:** Another way to phrase my question is, how exactly does Minecraft place its ores, and what would be the best way to do this in a 2d (From the side) game, using Perlin noise.

Answer (score 3):

You may place the lumps according to a random probability. However, with rare numbers this will mean that large areas will have no lumps, while some other places will be relatively rich in rare ores. A better algorithm might be: establish a base area, determine an acceptable density (e.g.: from one to three rare lumps per area), and then compute random locations for the rare lumps per area.

An example: you determine that it is acceptable to have 1-3 rare lumps in every 1000x1000 area. Then for every one of these areas you compute the number of rare lumps as `1+floor(random*3)` (where `0<random<1`), and compute random coordinates for the resulting rare lumps. You can also add constraints as minimum distance between rare lumps, for instance, which are not possible with random noise generators: if one rare lump would be placed too close to another rare lump, just recompute its location.

Answer (score 1):

The exact formula that Minecraft uses to generate terrain is a secret, as stated in [this](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/3746989361/terrain-generation-part-1) blog post by Notch.

I think that the best way to do this in a 2d Minecraft-ish game would be to generate the world block by block, with perlin noise (take a look at [this](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Perlin_noise.php) tutorial). Then when each block is created, send the X and Y to another function that will work out the likelihood of there being an ore in the block and if so, what ore it will be. If the function returns an ore you can then recreate the block as that ore.

Hope this helped. If you want more specific, coded examples just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I believe Minecraft's terrain is based on several octaves of Perlin noise generation, which is then smoothed by stretching. I assume that certain features are added in further passes, such as caves, overhangs and so on. It's very likely that you'll have to experiment with Perlin or another noise function to come up with a pleasing output for your landscape. The good thing about such noise functions is that with a given seed, they will give a predictable, repeatable output for a set of inputs, i.e. you can generate your landscape in chunks, like Minecraft's, without any discontinuities. There's more here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28970/c-perlin-noise-generating-endless-terrain-chunks

In terms of ore generation, having individual tiles of ore spread about in a random weighted distribution won't give you a very pleasant output. You would most likely prefer ore to be produced in natural-looking clumps. You can do this by using Perlin again to produce localised pockets or vertically-stretched veins of minable materials. You can either use the function as is and use your landscape heightmap as a cut-off point (so you don't end up with ore in mid-air!), or you can feed in your 1D landscape generation function as another input, meaning you can produce ore whose distribution is scaled for different depths. As for the rarity of the ore, you can use differing cut-off values from your 2D noise output for placement and also experiment with the frequency and persistence input values.

I like the cave generation functions given here: http://www.gamedev.net/blog/33/entry-2227887-more-on-minecraft-type-world-gen/ The ridged multi-fractals could certainly be adapted to generate ore patterns or other underground features, but there is increased complexity if you follow this approach.

**Edit:**

The first link may be to a question you yourself posted on gamedev! Are you the same Jon? :)

Comment: That is me :). Thanks for the reply, but that isn't quite what I'm looking for - I looked into the methods you suggest and with super rare ores... Well... Super rare ores won't be super rare.

Basically if you're familiar with Minecraft at all, there are common "ores" like coal which appear in clumps of 5-30, and super rare ores like diamonds that appear in clumps of 1-8 per chunk (And not every chunk even has diamonds) - this is more what I want. The problem with using straight up noise generation, is it's not predictable which number ranges are going to be rare, and which will be common.